# PayPal API "Get pay and payout"

Tags: paypal

I have this scenario:

**Web store Paypal account:** payments@mystore.com

**Personal Paypal Account:** manuel@mystore.com

In my web store I'm selling a product that cost $10 and I need help to create a script that after the customer pay the $10 using paypal, $8 go to the paypal email payments@mystore.com and the others $2 go to manuel@mystore.com

I tried using some examples I saw in the PayPal Docs but right now I can't post the scripts I have created.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use Adaptive Payment where you can split the payment to payments@mystore.com and another portion to manuel@mystore.com. There is a Paraller and Chained in Adaptive Payment. You can refer [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/) for a further details.